# Is every norm on a number field equivalent to some norm induced by an absolute value?

Tags: normed-spaces, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field. The nontrivial absolute values on $K$ are in correspondence with the embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}_v$, where $v$ is a place of $\mathbb{Q}$. Fix a nontrivial absolute value $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb{Q}$. A norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ on $K$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space is a function $\Vert \cdot \Vert : K \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ satisfying

1. If $x \in K$, then $\Vert x \Vert = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.
2. If $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and if $x \in K$, then $\Vert cx \Vert = |c| \Vert x \Vert$.
3. For any $x,y \in K$, $\Vert x + y \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert + \Vert y \Vert$.

Note every absolute value on $K$ lying above $|\cdot|$ induces a norm on $K$.

Two norms $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ are equivalent if there exist constants $A, B >0$ such that $$A \Vert x \Vert_1 \leq \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq B \Vert x \Vert_1$$ for all $x\in K$.

My first question is, given a norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ on $K$, is it equivalent to some norm induced by an absolute value on $K$?

In particular, if we fix a vector space basis for $K/\mathbb{Q}$, say $\beta = \{ \beta_1, \cdots,\beta_n\}$, we can define the *max norm* on $K$ as follows: $$\Vert a_1 \beta_1 + \cdots + a_n \beta_n \Vert_\beta := \max_{1\leq i \leq n} |a_i|.$$ Is the max norm equivalent to some absolute value on $K$? If so, can we say which absolute value that it's equivalent to, and perhaps even estimate the constants $A$ and $B$ from above?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has two inequivalent absolute values lying above $5$. How about their sum?

Comment: @Aphelli I see, their sum will be a norm on $\mathbb{Q} (i)$ which cannot be equivalent to either of the original absolute values.  More generally, this idea should work in any case where a prime splits in $K$.